# Trying to add a parameter to WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, hangfire

The following code was build using:

- Asp.net
- Hangfire
- AutoMapper
- C#
- Entity framework

So in my Global.cs file I have the following line at the start:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Governance.MissedChecker), "MissedCheckerSetup")]
```

That calls the following method:

```
public static void MissedCheckerSetup()
    {
       RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("missed_checker", () => Check(), "0 1 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    }
```

When this hangfire task is called it runs the method below:

```
    public static void Check()
    {
        var checkDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
        FillGapTasksService gapFiller = new FillGapTasksService();

        gapFiller.FillGapTasks();
}
```

Now my problem is that the FillGapTasksService needs a IMapper to be passed in so it can do some mapping, but I cannot pass it down through the PostApplicationStartMethod and doing any other way gives me an error.

Does anyone know how I can send an instance of the automapper IMapper to that service I'm calling in the last method?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection to inject IMapper instance in your project? If so, you can configure Hangfire to inject the IMapper [docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html). The list of supported IC containers is [here](https://www.hangfire.io/extensions.html#ioc-containers)

Comment: I have set this up and used an IoC container in other methods, but with the mapper I need to construct it? So I must be able to pass it through.